# How to create a valid TwilioML response object in node.js

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have a twilio webhook and I'm trying to structure the response with accordance with twiloML, I get an error response in twilio logs of

> 12200 The provided XML does not conform to the Twilio Markup XML
>   schema. Please refer to the specific error and correct the problem.

```
const twilio =  require('twilio');

function defaultTwilioSuccess(){
        var response = new twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
        response.message('its alive');
        return response.toString();
    }


exports.handler = function(event, context, callback){
    ...
    .then(function() {
         return callback(null, {
                    "statusCode": 200,
                    "headers": {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'},
                    "body":   JSON.stringify(defaultTwilioSuccess())
                });

            });
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the  `JSON.stringify` , is not needed in this case since its the respone is an XML format

```
return callback(null, {
                    "statusCode": 200,
                    "headers": {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'},
                    "body":  defaultTwilioSuccess()
                });

            });
```